# How Spring select Service Implementation?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have two projects in eclipse `siteBase` and `siteCustom`

siteBase have controller

```
public final class BaseController{
  
    @Autowired
    BaseService service;
  
    @POST
    @Path(/test)
    public final boolean test() {
      try {
        service.test();
      }
      catch (Throwable ex) {
        processException(ex);
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

A BaseService Interface

```
public interface BaseService extends BasicService{

    boolean test();

  }
```

And a BaseService Implementation

```
    public class BaseServiceImpl implements BaseService {

    public boolean test() {
        System.out.println("BaseServiceImpl");
        return true;
      }
    }
```

And in the siteCustom I have a other Implementation

public class BaseServiceCustomImpl implements BaseService {

```
public boolean test() {
    System.out.println("BaseServiceCustomImpl");
    return true;
  }
}
```

As I expect, when I `run siteBase` and call test controller have a console print:

> BaseServiceImpl

And if I `run siteCustom` and call test controller have a console print:

> BaseServiceCustomImpl

(I hope the code it's ok, but it's not problem, it's only for example purpose and It's not tested, it's only to explain the situation)

The other day, suddenly, when I `run siteCustom` the console show BaseServiceImpl... after some update it again works ok the console shows BaseServiceCustomImpl, but I want to understand exactly how Spring uses the Implementation and when and where decide which Implementation and its methods use.

Comment: `I hope the code it's ok, but it's not problem, it's only for example propouse and It's not tested, it's only to explain the situation` Please post the code that didnt work for you and paste the commands to reproduce it

Comment: The question it's not about a code, it's about how spring works... thats because the code it's not problem

Comment: Are all of those classes in one project only?

Comment: No, two projects in the same workspace. I can run one or another

Comment: Your question seems odd to me in that whenever I have provided multiple implementations for the same bean, Spring throws an exception because it doesn't know which one to inject. My application would then fail to start. Are both your implementations included and compiled in both projects?